# CSS width 100% isn't workin as expected

Tags: html, css, width

I'm trying to make a banner that fills all the screen horizontally but it isn't working as expected. There's some space that isn't fullfilled with it like you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5zep.png

I'd appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Best webpage ever</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">    
</head>    
<body>    
    <div class="banner">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Students</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">XXX tuga</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>    
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <p>cona</p>
        </div>          
    </div>    
    <div class="banner">                    
    </div>   
</body>
</html>

.banner{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: For a quick fix, you can add `body { margin:0; padding:0; }`, though it might be better to use a reset stylesheet - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ or `Normalize.css` - http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Try this, the body/html by default has padding, so you might want to try to remove that...

Comment: No problem friend, If you haven't already check out places such as: `w3schools` and `CSStricks` they are helpful and have some cool little things :)

Answer (score 0):

`body` tag applies some spacing in most browsers. Be sure to have:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css:

```
body{
  padding:0px;
}
```

let me know if that helps